# jQuery 1.6 not adding class to element on checkbox change

Tags: jquery

This code works fine with jQuery 1.5.1, but when I use jQuery 1.6.0 it changes the value of the checkbox after click, but it does not add the class 'done' to the element.

```
$("input:checkbox").live('change', function(eve) {
    eve.preventDefault();
    var el =  this.id ;
    var done =  this.done ;
    if( $(this).attr("checked") == true ) {
        $('#item-'+el).find(".text").addClass('done');
        //return false;
    }
    if( $(this).attr("checked") == false ) {
        $('#item-'+el).find(".text").removeClass('done');
        //return false;
    }

    $.post('taskDone.php', {
        id: this.id,
        value: $(this).attr("checked") ? 1 : 0
    }, function(data) {});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prior to 1.6

`$(this).attr("checked")` is inconsistent, as it can be a **boolean** or it can be a **string**

jQuery says something like: **attribute** is what's inside a property. so, it stopped sending you a `bool` value and it's sending you a `string` value instead.

if you change all

```
$(this).attr("checked")
```

to

```
$(this).prop("checked")
```

you will have no problems

---

from [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> For example, consider a DOM element defined by the HTML markup `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`, and assume it is in a JavaScript variable named elem:

```
elem.checked                       true (Boolean)
$(elem).prop("checked")            true (Boolean)
elem.getAttribute("checked")       "checked" (String)
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6+)      "checked" (String)
$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)   true (Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or update to version 1.6.1.
The attr() function will behave as in 1.5, so you don't have to crawl through your code to find every call to attr() and decide if you need to change it to prop().

Comment: No , I updated to version 1.6.1 , its easier for me but nothing happen , I think .prob is for 1.6 + ... thank you Patrick :)